# Is it possible to get current mouse cursor size in Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a custom cursor (SVG file) which is activated when hovering a button. I want this cursor to have the same size with default cursor on all platforms.

I wonder if it is possible to get default cursor size and set size of custom cursor accordingly.

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889487/get-size-of-mouse-cursor-in-javascript) almost 8 years ago. I was hoping it would be possible with new technologies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get size of mouse cursor in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889487/get-size-of-mouse-cursor-in-javascript)

Comment: @jakeehoffmann It was asked 8 years ago. I thought there might be a solution after 8 years.

Comment: If you know that your question is a duplicate, and you are asking in hopes of new technology, please link back to the duplicate and explain your reasoning for the duplicate. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258363/215552.

Answer (score 4):

There is no method or API of getting the size of the cursor on a user's OS. However, if you're adding a custom cursor, it is recommended you set its size to 32x32 as that is the size that is most compatible across most OS's.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no property to adjust cursor size with jquery. However since you are using a custom image you might find this useful:

http://www.ajaxblender.com/howto-create-custom-image-cursors.html.

This will show you how to create a custom cursor without a .cur file and add some css to adjust the size.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.